# efficent way to evalute multi label class models

Tags: python, multilabel-classification

does anyone have an idea about how to evaluate multi-label classifiers?
ie: when your label is not a single class but it can be multiple ones
i have tried calculating the Jaccard index for each observation then summing all the values but i don't think that s a good metric.

Comment: A confusion matrix is a typical tool to understand the performance of multiclass classifiers.